# Copying C++ allocators when allocator is inherited via EBCO

Tags: c++, containers, allocator

If a container obtains it's allocator's functions via EBCO ([empty base class optimisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo)) eg.:

```cpp
template <class T, class allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class a_container : private allocator;
```

What happens when that container has another container copied into it, and the other container's allocator is not equivalent (or empty)? If the new allocator has state, how is that state copied into the destination container, if the destination container's allocator was stateless? It seems like there would be no space in the actual class to store the state, if EBCO is used.

Secondly, how does the copying of the allocator take place?
Is `static_cast<allocator &>(*this) = source.get_allocator();` reasonable?

Comment: You cannot change the allocator type and you also generally can't copy between containers with different allocator types. If you have a specific example in mind, then please show it.

Comment: EBCO is irrelevant to the question. Whether you store the allocator as a private base or as a member, the interrelationships of allocators (whether one can hold the state of another, in particular) are unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens when that container has another container copied into it, and the other container's allocator is not equivalent?

A compile time error. `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>` is not assignable to `std::vector<T, some_other_allocator<T>>`, they are different classes.

> Secondly, how does the copying of the allocator take place?

Same as any other subobject that is trivially copyable. The 0 bytes of object representation are copied.

Comment: So what happens when the allocator isn't empty?
Will the code I demonstrated copy the state?

Comment: Allocators are copied based on allocator_traits::select_on_container_copy_construction. In other words, it's their choice whether to copy state or not.